# Mariadb : Looping while using UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, procedure

I wanna build query using variables, union all statement and loop in mariadb

I have a table named **stock_items** with this column down below

```
stock_list
===========================================
123123:A, 111111:B, 101010:C, 525252:D, ...
```

and i've used 'union all' statement like

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX (stock_items.stock_list,',',numbers.n),',',-1),':',1) stock_list FROM
(SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
) numbers 
INNER JOIN stock_items ON CHAR_LENGTH (stock_items.stock_list) - CHAR_LENGTH (REPLACE(stock_items.stock_list, ',', '')) >= numbers.n-1 WHERE theme_idx = 14 ;
```

to see like down below

```
stock_list
==========
123123
==========
111111
==========
101010
==========  ....
```

my question is in stock_list column of first one.
there could be random number of stocks. (currently it has 10 as you saw in my query but it can be more/less than 10)

so I want to build sql or procedure using User-Defined Variables, while, union-all statement.

cheers

Comment: What is the problem with the `union all` approach?

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB,

```
(SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
) numbers
```

can be written

```
seq_1_to_10
```

It is both a lot simpler and a lot faster.